# Rails routing and Rest : make resources alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have make some custom naming in Rails and I am not sure if I am still RestFull, and the way I am doing this is ugly.

I have two models `activity`, and `task` that both have managements: `activity_management` and `task_management`. Notice that managements are two differents models, because model behaviour are very different in my case.

In Rails, I start doing the following :

```
shallow do
   resources :activity do
        resources :activity_management
   end
   resources :task do
        resources :task_management
   end
end
```

And give me these route structure :

```
CREATE /activity/:activity_id/activity_management
SHOW /activity_management/:id

CREATE /task/:task_id/task_management
SHOW /task_management/:id
```

But I find these routes very long and giving repetitive informations (`CREATE` give twice the information that we are talking about an `activity`).

So I change to this :

```
shallow do
   resources :activity do
        resources :management, 
                  only: [:index, :new, :create], 
                  controller: :task_management
   end
   scope :activity do 
        resources :management, 
                  only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], 
                  controller: :task_management
   end
   resources :activity do
        resources :management, 
                  only: [:index, :new, :create], 
                  controller: :activity_management
   end
   scope :activity do 
        resources :management, 
                  only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], 
                  controller: :activity_management
   end
end
```

That give me this route structure :

```
CREATE /activity/:activity_id/management
SHOW /activity/management/:id

CREATE /task/:task_id/management
SHOW /task/management/:id
```

When the code start to be complicated, it's that I am doing something wrong... 
Do you see a simpler way to solve my problem ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly `activity_management` is a kind of backend to edit an activity and not an actual resource?

Comment: @max, no an `activity_management` is the resource that handle the people that manage an activity. For exemple, an activity is managed by 3 users, and 1 of them is sick, and remove his management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Your approach is not very RESTful or conventional.

If you need to separate parts of your application that are public facing and a dashboard or admin section backend you would normally set it up like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # public facing routes
  resources :activities, only: [:show, :index]
  resources :tasks, only: [:show, :index]

  namespace :management do
    resources :activities
    resources :tasks
  end
end
```

Note that you should be using the plural form for your routes and controllers!
This would create "public" routes at:

```
GET  /activities       ActivitiesController#index
GET  /activities/:id   ActivitiesController#show
```

And also namespaced routes:

```
GET|POST          /management/activities            
GET|PATCH|DELETE  /management/activities/:id
GET               /management/activities/new
GET               /management/activities/:id/edit
```

These routes would go to `Management::ActivitiesController`. This lets you provide different "representations" of a resource while still sticking to the rails conventions.

### Updated.

If you want to do resource scoped roles you would do it like so:

```
# routes rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :roles, except: [:new, :create]

  [:articles, :tasks].each do |resource_name|
    resources resource_name do
      resources :roles, only: [:create, :index], module: resource_name.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
        roles GET    /roles(.:format)                      roles#index
    edit_role GET    /roles/:id/edit(.:format)             roles#edit
         role GET    /roles/:id(.:format)                  roles#show
              PATCH  /roles/:id(.:format)                  roles#update
              PUT    /roles/:id(.:format)                  roles#update
              DELETE /roles/:id(.:format)                  roles#destroy
article_roles GET    /articles/:article_id/roles(.:format) articles/roles#index
              POST   /articles/:article_id/roles(.:format) articles/roles#create
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)                   articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)                   articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)               articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)          articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)               articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)               articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)               articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)               articles#destroy
   task_roles GET    /tasks/:task_id/roles(.:format)       tasks/roles#index
              POST   /tasks/:task_id/roles(.:format)       tasks/roles#create
        tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                      tasks#index
              POST   /tasks(.:format)                      tasks#create
     new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)                  tasks#new
    edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)             tasks#edit
         task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#show
              PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#update
              PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#update
              DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#destroy
```

---

This means to add a manager for a task you would do:

```
POST tasks/1/roles
{
  name: "manager",
  user_id: 666
}
```

---

```
# - resource_id   [integer]
# - resource_type [string]
# - user_id       [integer, foreign key]
# - name          [string]
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorpic: true
  belings_to :user
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, as: :resource
  # ...
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, as: :resource
  # ...
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
end

 # do the normal index, delete, update here
class RolesController < ApplicationController
  # ...
end

# abstract controller class for reuse
class NestedRolesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_resource

  def create
    @role = @resource.roles.create(role_params)
    respond_with(@role)
  end

  def role_params
    params.require(:role).permit(:user_id, :name)
  end
end

class Articles::RolesController < NestedRolesController
  def set_resource
    @resource = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  end
end

class Tasks::RolesController < NestedRolesController
  def set_resource
    @resource = Task.find(params[:task_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want to re-use specific routes for different resources you would use routing concerns however I hardly think this is such a case.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I am looking for. A management is a resource, because in our app, you can give a management-role to someone else, or just give it up. I want to CRUD a management for both a task and an activity.
Thanks for plural comment, I update my question.

Comment: Well actually, this resolve my problem. Just need to think a bit diferently. Thanks

Comment: Good, resource scoped roles is the general pattern for what it sounds like what you are trying to do. You might want to check out the Rolify library that provides all the model level components needed to make a good system that is resuable and hooks into your authorization.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
['task','activity'].each do |manager|
  resources :activity do
    resources :management, 
      only: [:index, :new, :create], 
      controller: "#{manager}_management".to_sym
  end
  scope :activity do 
    resources :management, 
      only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], 
      controller: "#{manager}_management".to_sym
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have two shallow resources with the same name. You can provide a `shallow_path` to differentiate them. You can also shorten your resource URL with `path`. Don't forget to add `shallow: true` on the nested resources.

```
scope shallow_path: "activity"
  resources :activity do
    resources :activity_management, path: 'management', shallow: true
  end
end

scope shallow_path: "task"
  resources :task do
    resources :task_management, path: 'management', shallow: true
  end
end
```

Comment: the output won't be this one, because the shallow, that will give `management/:id` for both `SHOW`. I need that they go to two different controller.

Comment: Adding ```path``` just changes the URL, it still maps it to the controller identified as the first parameter in ```resources```. Add a shallow prefix to fix the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the **routes** you're looking for (I think) with fairly little code, but the controller actions will all be namespaced as 'task_management/management#action' so you'd need to account for that:

```
resources :task do
  member do
    resources :management, module: 'task_management', shallow: true
  end
end

resources :activity do
  member do
    resources :management, module: 'activity_management', shallow: true
  end
end
```

You can alternatively list the matches explicitly, which is more verbose but will namespace the controller actions a little more cleanly:

```
resources :task do
  member do
    match '/management' => 'task_management#index', :via => :get
    match '/management/:id' => 'task_management#show', :via => :get
    match '/management' => 'task_management#create', :via => :post
    match '/management' => 'task_management#update', :via => :put
    match '/management' => 'task_management#delete', :via => :delete
  end
end
```